# Cannot assign "9": "Characterweapons.weaponid" must be a "Weapons" instance

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, django-views

I've been reading similar questions to mine but they didn't help me.

I'm getting this error while I try to submit my form:

```
Cannot assign "9": "Characterweapons.weaponid" must be a "Weapons" instance.
```

This "9" is the ID from the weapon I got from my form, so that's very good, but when I try to put it in my weaponid column in my table Characterweapons, it gives me the error.

models.py:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models


class Category(models.Model):
    categoryid = models.AutoField(db_column='CategoryID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    categoryname = models.CharField(db_column='CategoryName', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'category'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.categoryname

class Characters(models.Model):
    characterid = models.AutoField(db_column='CharacterID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    name = models.CharField(db_column='Name', unique=True, max_length=255)  # Field name made lowercase.
    level = models.IntegerField(db_column='Level')  # Field name made lowercase.
    credits = models.IntegerField(db_column='Credits')  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'characters'

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s %s' % (self.name, self.level, self.credits)

class Weapons(models.Model):
    weaponid = models.AutoField(db_column='WeaponID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    weaponname = models.CharField(db_column='WeaponName', unique=True, max_length=255)  # Field name made lowercase.



    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'weapons'

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %r' % (self.weaponname, self.weaponid)       

class Characterweapons(models.Model):
    characterid = models.ForeignKey(Characters, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='CharacterID')  # Field name made lowercase.
    weaponid = models.ForeignKey(Weapons, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='WeaponID', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    categoryid = models.ForeignKey(Category, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='CategoryID', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    quantity = models.IntegerField(db_column='Quantity', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'characterweapons'
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.quantity)



class DjangoMigrations(models.Model):
    app = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    applied = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'django_migrations'
```

I don't know if it is a FK problem, PK... no idea and I cannot find information to solve it...

views.py: (where the error has to be):

```
def submission(request):

    print("Registered successfully")
    Name = request.POST["Name"]
    Level = request.POST["Level"]
    Credits = request.POST["Credits"]
    Mainhand = request.POST["Mainhand"]
    Offhand = request.POST["Offhand"]

    info = Characters(name=Name,level=Level,credits=Credits)
    info.save()
    mh=
    infomh = Weapons.objects.values_list('weaponid',flat=True)
    a=0;
    for a in infomh:
        if a == Mainhand:
            a = Mainhand;

    print("a: ")
    print(a)
    print("Mainhand")
    print(Mainhand)
    print("infmh:")
    print(infomh)

    charid = Characters.objects.latest('characterid')
    info_mh = Characterweapons(characterid=charid,categoryid=1,weaponid=a)
    info_mh.save()
    #info_oh =  Characterweapons(characterid=charid,weaponid=9,categoryid=2)
    #info_oh.save()



    return return_charnames(request)
```

With these prints I made sure that the values of my weaponsID are correct, they are.
I also wanna point out that the value=9 in the column "weaponid" exists in "Weapons" table.
Thanks all.

Comment: Form data is submitted as a string.  It looks like `weaponid` is an integer.  Perhaps this is the issue?

Comment: Well a `ForeignKey` in the django layer is actually a reference to a `Weapon` instance, that is why you should not name your fields `weaponid`, but just `weapon`. Then you can create an instance with `weapon_id=a`, if you do not want to rename it is `weaponid_id`, but you probably already see that this generates bad nomenclature.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem you just fixed my error, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you better first fix your models. In Django a `ForeignKey` is conceptually a *reference* to an object to which you refer, not the id. Of course in the database it is stored as an id, but that is a layer that you should not care much about.

So I would advice to first rename the fields like `weaponid` to `weapon`:

```
class Characterweapons(models.Model):
    character = models.ForeignKey(Characters, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='CharacterID')
    weapon = models.ForeignKey(Weapons, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='WeaponID', blank=True, null=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='CategoryID', blank=True, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(db_column='Quantity', blank=True, null=True)

    # ...
```

Now if you construct a `ForeignKey` with the name `fieldname`, Django actually introduces two fields: the `fieldname` which is - like said before - a reference to a model object to which the `ForeignKey` refers, and a field `fieldname_id` that stores the `id` (the primary key) of that object. These two fields thus act like "twins".

We can then rewrite the `submission` view like:

```
def submission(request):
    print("Registered successfully")
    name = request.POST["Name"]
    level = request.POST["Level"]
    credits = request.POST["Credits"]
    mainhand = request.POST["Mainhand"]
    offhand = request.POST["Offhand"]

    info = Characters.objects.create(name=name, level=level,credits=credits)
    if Weapons.objects.filter(weapon_id=mainhand).exists():
        a = mainhand

    info_mh = Characterweapons.objects.create(
        character_id=info.pk,
        category_id=1,
        weapon_id=a
    )
    return return_charnames(request)
```

In the above I did some refactorings as well:

1. In Python variables in functions typically have lowercase names;
2. you do not need to loop over `weapon_id`s, you can use an `EXISTS` query, which is typically faster;
3. Instead of first constructing a model instance, and then `obj.save()` it, you can use `Model.objects.create(..)` instead;
4. you probably do not want to fetch the `latest(..)` value, but use the `pk` of the `info` object instead, since that is the one we constructed, and furthermore if there is no order defined (like here), the order can be any order the database likes, not per se the latest one added.

You probably still need to rewrite hardcoded identifiers (like `a=1`, and `category_id=1`, since it is perfectly possible that those objects do *not* exist in the database).

Comment: Totally agree, this was my first time and it was pretty sloppy, i'll apply the changes you suggested, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Your foreignkey weaponid in the model Characterweapons  is a Weapon instance not only its id. 
From that id, query the object and assign it.